# How can I write a file from one server to another server in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to write a file from on server to another server?

I have 2 domains both are on diffrent web servers

http://example1.com is on [godady](http://godady.com) and http://example2.com is on a free webhost [eu5.org](http://eu5.org) ,

I want to write htaccess file of http://example1.com from http://example2.com .

my code in example2.com

```
$code =$_POST["cd"];

if (empty($code)) {
    echo "Could not insert data!";
} else {
    $file = fopen("http://server2.com/.htaccess", "w");

    echo fwrite($file, $code);
    fclose($file);
}
```

It does'nt rewrite the .htaccess file and no php error. file permision of example1/.htaccess is 777.

Any idea?

Comment: Imagine the reprocussions if it were this easy to write a file to a server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a file on another server using PHP file functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288187/creating-a-file-on-another-server-using-php-file-functionality)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:

"Yes.  It possible to write a file from on server to another server"

To write any file to any server across the network, you need to:

1) decide on a protocol (for example, [ftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)), then

2) instantiate a "listener" on the host to accept client requests for that protocol (for example, installing [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server) on your Windows host)

Since you're writing in PHP - and since PHP is already using a protocol (HTTP) and already has a "listener" (your web server) -then why not just write a PHP app to accept files for upload, and send files for download?

Here's a simple example:

- http://justinpaulin.com/2012/09/03/a-simple-server-to-server-file-transfer-script-php/

Whatever you choose to do, make sure it's *secure*.  In particular, you should *not* be able to "re-write .htaccess", and you should *not* be able to read or write to any arbitrary directory.